# After installing raspbian I can't add ssh file

Tags: raspbian, ssh, pi-3b+

After I installed raspbian on the sdcard, the sd card disapear from the file explorer and I can't add a ssh file.

If I plug out and in the sd card, windows ask me to reformat.

How could I add the ssh file to the sdcard ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the partition where the `ssh` file lives is formatted in a way so it remains visible in Windows. Perhaps you flashed a wrong/damaged image?

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour of Windows 10 changed recently.

After writing the Raspbian image to the SD card you have to eject and re-insert it in your SD card reader. You have to cancel the format requests and after that you can write the ssh file to the card to enable SSH as usual